# Relationship between Push Segues, Navigation controllers, and Tool/Nav Bars

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue, uitoolbar

[image]

So above I have a picture of my current storyboard and I have a few questions to clarify my understanding:

**1)** Am I correct to assume when I do a push segue way from my first VC to my second VC that my second VC would be on top of the stack?

**2)** Would there be any reason at all to embed another Navigation Controller in my second VC? Or would it be redundant.

**3)** As I wanted both my Navigation and Toolbars to show on my second VC when the push segue happened I made both my Top and Bottom Bars Translucent, is there a better way to do this?

**4)** How would I be able to access the bottom toolbar of the second VC? I know that I can access the navigation bar via `self.navigationController?.navigationBar` but I can't seem to find a way for the bottom toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. It would likely be redundant. It's possible that it may be useful as a child view controller but that's unlikely and would probably lead to unexpected things in future.
3. That's fine (unless it isn't working / looking correct for the user)
4. I see why Q3 now. That option is for when the view controller is inside a tab bar controller for example, and used to help with the space available for layout. If you want an explicit toolbar on the view then you should explicitly add it as a sub-view.

Comment: Could you clarify on the function of making the nav and tool bars translucent? I'm still a bit blurry on the concept, what is the purpose of doing that? And also is there a way to change the Navigation Bar that is pushed when the segue happens how would I access that?

Comment: It just sets up in the storyboard that you expect them to be there so you can see the space available and add bar buttons. But, if the container doesn't create them then they won't actually be there to be used. It's a convenience.

Comment: Oh right so it's just for us to see how to layout the UI when we are designing it but it doesn't affect the end product at all?

Comment: If you put something in it, like your cancel or plus bar button, then it can - but it depends on the container as well as the contained view controller as to exactly what happens

Comment: So the Navigation Controller has a toolbar and a navbar that won't change for all the VC's that are in the array of the Navigation Controller? And the only way that we are able to make our own specific tool/nav bar in the VC's on the stack is to add the bars to the subviews?

Comment: A navigation controller explicitly contains a nav bar, controllers pushed onto the stack will be asked for their nav item and it will be used to update the nav bar. Navigation controllers do not explicitly have a tab bar so the same thing doesn't happen there. You would need to handle the tool bar yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96131/discussion-between-yellowpillow-and-wain).